# addEventListener click not working after using similar function to open a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, addeventlistener

Im having issues with getting addEventListener to close a form that I opened using addEventListener.

For example, here is my HTML, CSS and JS for opening the form:

```js
let addAlarmLink = document.getElementById('alarm-add');
let addAlarmForm = document.getElementById('adding-alarm');

addAlarmLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (addAlarmForm.style.display === 'none' || addFriendForm.style.display === 'none') {
        addAlarmForm.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        addAlarmForm.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
#adding-alarm {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
 
<section id="adding-alarm" style="display: none;">
        <form id="alarm-form">
        <h5 id="close">X</h5>
        <h4>Adding Alarm</h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="n-name" placeholder="Nickname" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="f-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="l-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" >
        <h4>Login Info </h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="add-username-email" placeholder="Username or Email of Friend" type="text" >
        <input class="login-info" id="add-alarm-submit" type="submit" value="Add Alarm">
        
    </form>
</section>
```

This works fine, the form opens and is editable. However, when setting up a addEventListener to close the form, its not triggering or even being recognized. Here's the code for that:

```
let closeForm = document.getElementById('close');



closeForm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    addAlarmForm.display.style = 'none';
    
});
```

This did not work and i tried it a few other ways by using onClick and setting up a function but had the same results. I also tried setting up a console.log to just spit out a message and i get nothing in the console. One other thing i noticed is that style gets pushed out of  #adding-alarm to element.style when inspecting the styles.

[picture of style showing under element.style rather than updating #adding-alarm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2PCZ.png)

Is there something im doing wrong or a better to make this happen?

This is all very new to me.

Comment: Plz provide your code having `id` `alarm-add`

Comment: <div class="add-option">
        <p>Add an alarm to be reminded to do a task.</p>
        <i id="alarm-add" class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </div>

Comment: Didi you checked the way below answer told

Comment: @Rana yes i did. That was not the solution. It seems that its not triggering the 'click' event since the console.log I tested didnt show anything.

Comment: I provided a working code in below answer tell if it solves the problem or there is any other problem I don't caught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine taken from your code only . Here is a working example in snippet below ,the only problem was told in the other answer that is `.style.display` is wrongly written as `.display.style` .

```js
let addAlarmLink = document.getElementById('alarm-add');
let addAlarmForm = document.getElementById('adding-alarm');

addAlarmLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (addAlarmForm.style.display === 'none' || addFriendForm.style.display === 'none') {
    addAlarmForm.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    addAlarmForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

let closeForm = document.getElementById('close');
closeForm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    addAlarmForm.style.display = 'none';
    
});
```

```css
#adding-alarm {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-option"> <p>Add an alarm to be reminded to do a task.</p> <i id="alarm-add" class="fas fa-plus-circle">+</i> </div>

<section id="adding-alarm" style="display: none;">
        <form id="alarm-form">
        <h5 id="close">X</h5>
        <h4>Adding Alarm</h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="n-name" placeholder="Nickname" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="f-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="l-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" >
        <h4>Login Info </h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="add-username-email" placeholder="Username or Email of Friend" type="text" >
        <input class="login-info" id="add-alarm-submit" type="submit" value="Add Alarm">
        
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: I have that exact code and its not producing results. So i must have something elsewhere breaking the code. Im going to take a break and try to search for it with fresh eyes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome , ready to help anytime

Answer (score 0):

Notice mixed up order of properties. In working case you have:

```
addAlarmForm.style.display = 'block';
```

And in not working case you have:

```
addAlarmForm.display.style = 'none';
```

This is likely to be your error. However, you said nothing is showing on the console, and it's suspicious because clearly there should be some error on the console (display is not defined on HTMLElement)

Comment: That did not do the trick and i think i got that turned around when trying different methods but thanks, i know i would have gotten caught up on that once id gotten further. Ive also added the HTML for opening the form above in the comments. also i cant add a photo but i can confirm that my console stays 100% blank when clicking the X.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually running fine. it only need some clean up and few adjustment,
here is some adjustment I made to your code and it works as expected.

```js
let addAlarmLink = document.getElementById('showForm');
let closeForm = document.getElementById("closeForm");
let addAlarmForm = document.getElementById('adding-alarm');

let addAlarmSubmit = document.getElementById("add-alarm-submit");

addAlarmLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (addAlarmForm.style.display === 'none') {
        addAlarmForm.style.display = 'block';
        addAlarmLink.style.display = 'none';
        closeForm.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        addAlarmForm.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

if(closeForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addAlarmForm.style.display = 'none';
    closeForm.style.display = 'none';
    addAlarmLink.style.display = 'block';
}));

if(addAlarmForm.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('form submitted successfully..!')
}));
```

```css
#adding-alarm {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<button id="showForm">show form</button>
<button id="closeForm" style="display: none;">Close form</button>

<section id="adding-alarm" style="display: none;">
        <form id="alarm-form">
        
        <h4>Adding Alarm</h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="n-name" placeholder="Nickname" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="f-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" >
        <input class="add-form-info" id="l-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" >
        <h4>Login Info </h4>
        <input class="add-form-info" id="add-username-email" placeholder="Username or Email of Friend" type="text" >
        <input class="login-info" id="add-alarm-submit" type="submit" value="Add Alarm">
    </form>
</section>
```